# Sql query with dynamic questions outerjoined to a table (need to filter data)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables. A [customer] table, [dynamicquestions] table, and [dynamicanswers] table.
The customer table contains customer submitted data.
The dynamicquestions table contains the dynamic questions the customer needs to answer.
And the dynamicanswers table are the answers the customer submitted. (these answers are keyed to the dynamicquestions table and keyed to the customer table.

What I am doing is dynamically creating unique column names for these dynamic questions. And then pivoting the dynamic answers into the dynamically created column names.

This all works. My problem, is I want to filter and a customer that has submitted an answer to two dynamic questions.

for example: if there are dynamic questions "how old are you" and "what state do you live in". I want to get everyone that answered "30" and "Texas".

Below is an example query with an "OR statement But I need it to be some sort of "Get both if the customer answered "30" and "Texas".

```sql
DECLARE @docDates VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @docDates = STUFF((
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar, REPLACE(QAPanelName,'QA_','')) + CONVERT(varchar, LEN(Orderbynumber)) + CONVERT(varchar, Orderbynumber) + CONVERT(varchar, ControlID) + '_' + QuestionColumnName)
FROM DynamicAnswers RIGHT OUTER JOIN DynamicQuestions ON DynamicAnswers.FK_Answers_ControlID = DynamicQuestions.ControlID
WHERE FK_DynamicQuestions_Topic = 56 
ORDER BY ', '  + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar, REPLACE(QAPanelName,'QA_','')) + CONVERT(varchar, LEN(Orderbynumber)) + CONVERT(varchar, Orderbynumber) + CONVERT(varchar, ControlID) + '_' + QuestionColumnName)
FOR XML PATH('')
)
, 1, 1, '')

--------------------------------------------

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT  Country,eMail,ShortTalk,InvoiceNum, CONVERT(varchar, REPLACE(QAPanelName,''QA_'','''')) + CONVERT(varchar, LEN(Orderbynumber)) + CONVERT(varchar, Orderbynumber) + CONVERT(varchar, ControlID) + ''_'' + QuestionColumnName AS FK_Answers_ControlID, DynamicAnswers.Answer
FROM             customer LEFT OUTER JOIN DynamicQuestions INNER JOIN DynamicAnswers ON DynamicQuestions.ControlID = DynamicAnswers.FK_Answers_ControlID 
                 ON DynamicAnswers.FK_Answers_customer = customer.InvoiceNum
WHERE( DynamicQuestions.FK_DynamicQuestions_Topic = 56  AND  (Deleted = 0 AND customer.SubmissionConfirmed = 1  AND FK_customer_Topic = 56  AND (Cancelled = 0)  AND ( (DynamicQuestions.ControlID = 42 AND DynamicAnswers.Answer = ''30'')  OR (DynamicQuestions.ControlID = 43 AND DynamicAnswers.Answer = ''Texas'') ) AND FK_DynamicQuestions_Topic = 56 ) )) AS[SubTable]
PIVOT
(
MAX(Answer)
FOR[FK_Answers_ControlID] IN(' + @docDates + ')
) AS[Pivot]; '
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: yep.  i'll fix that.  any idea of how to fix the query?